# Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hey Friends i need a Solution to fix this Error

> Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-site\wp-content\themes\kingdom\woocommerce\content-single-product.php on line 18

The Line of PHP File:

```
$cat_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
$tag_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );
```

Comment: What does get_the_terms() return?

Comment: Exactly what I meant. But it clearly does not return an array or object.

Answer (score 9):

Normally `get_the_terms`  return either object if the term exist if not it's return  false that's why you have this error .

so just add condition to your code to check if `get_the_terms` is true count the terms by adding  `sizeof`  if not just return 0 in your variable :

```
$cat_count = (get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat')) ? sizeof(get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat')) : 0;
$tag_count = (get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_tag')) ? sizeof(get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_tag')) : 0;
```

[Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wp_count_terms` as it seems you only need the count here

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_terms/